# Technical reasons to use of if statement that returns True/False rather than directly casting the conditional expression to bool

Tags: python

I was looking at an online course called "Advanced Python" and noticed several cases where `if` statements that returned `True` were used instead of for instance directly returning the condition expression as a boolean. Below is an example based on what I saw in the course:

```
def foo(x):
    if x.isupper():
       return True
    return False


def bar(x):
    return bool(x.isupper())


def usage():
    s = "Hello World!"
    return list(filter(foo, s)
```

As I'm more experienced in other languages, are there technical reasons to prefer `foo` over `bar`?  Perhaps it's a defensive style related to not necessarily knowing the type of the argument?

Comment: Neither is preferred. Just `return x.isupper()` You almost never need to explicitly convert to `bool`, any object can be used in a boolean context anyway, certainly it isn't necessary when you pass to `filter`, for example... Quite frankly, if you are taking a course called "advanced Python" and they have a lot of constructions like `def foo`, I would ... take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: Neither is idiomatic. `isupper` returns a `bool`

Comment: Also, don't name your variable `str`, it shadows the builtin type.

Comment: As others commented it's just a preference that author chose.

Comment: @PeterWood there is at least one example of a mainstream class with an `isupper` method that does not return a bool, viz. `numpy.chararray`. Not standard lib but pretty standard still. That said, if the given snippets are meant as a precaution it will not help in that case.

Comment: @PaulPanzer we're talking about `str` objects.

Comment: @PaulPanzer well, even in `numpy` `chararray` is not longer standard, mostly kept around for backwards compatibility, but even given that, this would make *even less sense* in this context because `numpy.chararray` (numpy arrays in general) are one of the *exceptions* to objects that can be used in a boolean context!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, standard may be too strong a word, how about "something one may realistically expect to pop up occasionally". Anyway, clumsy as the snippets may look I have encountered cases (can't remember which library with unfortunately) where I had to do something very similar because only a proper bool would do, and a (scalar) `numpy.bool` would not be accepted.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Also, I feel that the mere fact that such an important exception as numpy arrays exist makes the idea that everything should have a natural truthiness to it look rather dubious. I'm sure you are aware of that `[0]` vs. `np.array([0])` example. For me this alone is reason enough to be very suspicious of python's to bool coercion behavior.

Comment: @PaulPanzer a numeric array is different to a generic list. You should have different expectations. Also, I would say it's dubious that `numpy` has implemented it like that, but it's probably for efficiency. Requiring the user to use `not any` or similar would put the code execution in the Python interpreter rather than the `numpy` C/Fortran implementation, and the point of `numpy` is efficiency.

Comment: @PeterWood It seems perfectly logical to me. Scalar operations when applied to arrays are by convention done element by element. `np.array([0])` coercing to anything but `np.array([False])` would break all sorts of contracts. Or do you mean by dubious that this array can act as a scalar? I'd have to agree with you on that one. I don't really understand what you mean by `not any`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer compared with a `list` where `bool([0])` is `True`. To get the same behaviour as `np.array` you'd have to say `any([0])`. Apologies, I wasn't thinking when I included the `not`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe since Python is dynamic typed, using `foo` method returns a perception of more control on the type that is returned - but is useless. Besides this, the methods are equivalent.